# Calcluating the photon propagator with gauge fixing parameter

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, propagator

I'm trying to calculate the photon propagator via the functional integral, with lagrangian (plus source)

$L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{ab}F_{ab} - \frac{\lambda}{2}\left(\partial^aA_a\right)^2 + J^aA_a $

where lambda is a gauge fixing parameter and we are working in the 'mostly plus' convention for the metric.

We define $Q^{ab} = \eta^{ab} - (1-\lambda)\frac{k^ak^b}{k^2} $.

Modulo minus signs (I'm sure i need to flip the order of 1 and $\lambda$ in  $Q^{ab}$), I've arrived at the expression (where $Z = \int DA e^{iS}$)

$S = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} d^4x d^4y \frac{e^{i(y-x)k}J_c(x)Q^{cd}J_d(y)}{k^2-i\epsilon} - \frac{e^{ik(y-x)}Q^b_aJ_b(x)J^a(y)}{k^2-i\epsilon} - \frac{e^{ik(y-x)}Q^b_aJ_b(y)J^a(x)}{k^2-i\epsilon}  $

I see that the first term in this expression contains the propagator I am looking for (given by $\Delta_{ab}(x,y) = \int \frac{d^4k}{\left(2\pi\right)^4}e^{ik(x-y)}\frac{Q_{ab}}{k^2-i\epsilon}$), but I feel like the other terms could affect the result when taking the functional derivatives. Is this expression what we need or am I right in thinking some further cancellation should occur?

Also, in Srednicki, he simply states the formula for the propagator in his sections on the free theory path integral, rather than deriving it. Is it enough to define the propagator as $(-i\frac{\delta}{\delta J(x)}) (-i\frac{\delta}{\delta J(y)}) Z(J)|_{J=0}$ even in an interacting theory or does it have some other more complicated expression in different theories? For example, could I simply state that the result follows from taking the functional derivatives above?

Thanks in advance.